# Getting ORA-01031 in Oracle while trying to embedded java code in stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper, oracle19c

I use the PL/SQL developer app when accessing the database I need to CRUD data in my app.  We recently went from **Oracle 12c to 19** upgrade and getting an `ORA-01031` error when trying to compile java source codes that are used in a few triggers and procedures.  *It works in Oracle 12c but not in Oracle 19.*

I try to troubleshoot with the DBA guys and they say it might be a JDK issue.  But the JDK on my end is up to date with what the DBA is telling me.  When I try to compile the java source code I get these error messages:

```
ORA-01031 Insufficient privileges and error: illegal character;"\\u0000' and error: reached end of file while parsing.
```

I crossed all of the t's, dotted the i's, and checked all the {}s.  The lines the error messages show that occurred are below my last }, which is the public class {}.

I am just lost in what I need to do.  Any suggestions.  The java classes(function) are causing the error.  it's not just one, it's all of the java classes causing the error and I have 5 of them.  Again works fine in Oracle 12c

```
create or replace procedure OracleProcedure (column1 NUMBER, 
column2 NUMBER, column3 NUMBER, column4 NUMBER,column5VARCHAR2)
as language java name 'javaSource.functionName(int, int, int, int, 
java.lang.String)';
```

embedded java code looks like this minus the logic

```
create or replace and compile java source named javaSource as
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class javaSource
 {

  public static void functionName(int columnA, int columnB, int columnC, 
int columnD, String columnE) throws SQLException
  {

  int ncolumnB = columnB;         
  String cColumnB= "";
  cColumnB = Integer.toString(ncolumnB);

  String cColumnE = null;

  java.util.Date dColumnE1 = null;
  java.util.Date dColumnE2 = null;

  cColumnB = "123";

Statement statement0 = null;
ResultSet resultset0 = null;

Statement statement1 = null;
ResultSet resultset1 = null;

boolean lResults0;

Connection connection = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();

String query1 = "select ... ";

statement0 = connection.createStatement();
resultset0 = statement0.executeQuery(query1);

String cNo;
Date dDate_Opened = null;
int nKey = gkey;
int nEKey = 0;

while(resultset0.next()){
  ...
}  

  if (nEKey != 0) {

  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "mm/dd/yyyy" );

  try {  
  dStartDate1 = sdf.parse( columnE );
  }
  catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }


  try {

      ...
  }
  catch (ParseException e) {
   
    e.printStackTrace();
  }


  if (dStartDate1.getTime() -  dStartDate2.getTime() > 0 ) {
     //Use the cStart_Date2 since this is the newest date
     cStart_Date1=cStart_Date2;
  }

 if (... ){

  String query2 = "update ...";
  statement1 = connection.createStatement();
  resultset1 = statement1.executeQuery(query2);      
  }

  } else {

  String query2 = "insert into ..."; 
  statement1 = connection.createStatement();
  resultset1 = statement1.executeQuery(query2);      
  }
}
}
```

Comment: The question title doesn't make sense. Any such Oracle error would have to occur at runtime. We need to see code

Comment: Do you mean Java code calling Oracle; or embedded Java procedures stored inside the database?

Comment: Please see edit in question.  they are embedded java procedures stored inside the database.  The above procedure compiles with error due to java source.  JavaSource just had regular jdbc codes in there, with couple select and updateds

Comment: You mention braces {} in your question but do not show the code.  You need to show a [mcve].

Comment: I posted how the code looks minus all the details, which i dont't think is causing the ORA-01031 Insufficient privileges and error: illegal character;"\\u0000' and error: reached end of file while parsing.